# Method not found error in JSTL

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I have a class in my project.

```
@Component
public class Overview {

   public SomeData getData() {
       ...
       return new SomeData();
   }
}
```

In XHTML, I used `#{overview.getData()}` and is working perfectly. We are using JSTL, JSF 2.

I added a method in the existing class which returns a string.

```
public String sayHi()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Then I added `#{overview.sayHi()}`. It's showing error

> Method does not exist

Do I need to add any configuration?

Comment: I guess you need to update the TLD , is it ?

Comment: To what kind of component/event have you added the `#{overview.sayHi()}` method ?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot. Thank you for reply. I am not sure why this error occurring for newly added methods. Previous methods are working fine.

Comment: @kocko. I am trying to add it to .xhtml page and display a simple string

Comment: I understand, but I want to know what kind of component are you using? Is it `<c:out>`, or `<h:outputText>`, or .. ?

Comment: @Girish: please do not format non-code as code.

Comment: @Patan: did you clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart to exclude a dirty environment from being the cause? Adding new methods during runtime development works only if your environment supports hot code replacement.

Comment: @patan first confirm whether the method does exists within a class by De-compiling it surely it is not present over there.

Comment: try changing the method name to getSayHi() and then use #{overview.sayHi}